# Using the Flex propety align-self on an absolute positioned element - not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to horizontally center the .before-text using align-self. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but of course not in IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/jjcnoh6b/2/

Stack snippet

```css
.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.before-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="before-text">Pre-Header Text</div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate ratione accusantium, porro consequatur, velit praesentium laboriosam, fuga sapiente sequi neque recusandae officia. Consequuntur temporibus fugit deserunt cupiditate libero blanditiis
    veritatis.
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't, you need `transform: translate` to make that work in IE (and Safari)

The main reason is that the specs. been changed and so far only Chrome/Firefox/Edge has catched up, and the good news is, this work cross browser.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjcnoh6b/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.before-text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   font-size: 11px;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="before-text">Pre-Header Text</div>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate ratione accusantium, porro consequatur, velit praesentium laboriosam, fuga sapiente sequi neque recusandae officia. Consequuntur temporibus fugit deserunt cupiditate libero blanditiis veritatis.</p>
  
</div>
```